# SSL: If I connect from my site to another site's API that hasn't SSL, is the connection protected?

Tags: api, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have to connect to the API of a lot of websites and some of those haven't an SSL connection.

How can I protect the connection on my (server) side? If I use an SSL encrypted connection, is this secure?

They are websites of third parties, based on Woocommerce, PrestaSHop, Magento and similar. I want to connect to them to import some data, but may happen they haven't an SSL connection. How can I secure the connection and the data?

Comment: If you are connecting to a non ssl endpoint then no it is not encrypted. If you have a VPN connection between your server and the endpoint then it is more secure

Comment: I don't think I can create a VPN. Are websites of third parties, based on Woocommerce, PrestaSHop, Magento and similar. I want to connect to them to import some data, but may happen they haven't an SSL connection. How can I secure the connection and the data?

Comment: You can't. If the endpoints  contain sensitive data they should have some means of connecting via ssl. If you are just pulling publicly available data there isn't really a need for a secure connection in most cases

Answer (score 0):

> I want to connect to them to import some data, but may happen they haven't an SSL connection.

If your main goal is to get the data and not use transactional request then you may probably ask these company for your data without using non-encrypted connection.

If you want to connect on their APi then you will have to use what they are serving, and if it is non-secure API then there is no way to secure it.

> They are websites of third parties, based on Woocommerce, PrestaSHop, Magento and similar.

Maybe you can connect directly on Woocommerce API or PrestaSHop or magento to fetch the data directly using SSL.

For Magento there is a way to configure it :
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_ssl.htm

For WooCommerce:
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/ssl-faq/

For PrestaHops:
https://www.prestashop.com/blog/en/guest-blogger-series-prestashop-ssl-installation-troubleshooting/

If it is not an option then you will have to ask the third party to use SSL connection to encrypt the data.

Comment: Yes, I know it is possible, but not all merchants configure the SSL on their sites because they haven't a digital certificate. So I'm looking for a solution to get those data from their non-protected sites but in a secure way on my own side so granting the security of the connection and avoid thefts of data...

Comment: Can't you just get the data in zip file with encryption using a password? Could be a minimum security. If there is no confidential information about user or the data don't need a high protection it could be the answer. In any case there is no way you can do something without a modification on the merchant site or API without their implication.

Comment: No, I cannot use zip files: the APIs give me json or XML data and i cannot compress them on the merchant's server.

Comment: Then there is absolutely no way to achive what you are trying to do since the data is served on the merchant side. You may contact them directly to add security on their websites and services. Or you may hack them and add security (which could be illegal ;))

Comment: "Or you may hack them and add security (which could be illegal ;))" ah ah ah ah ;) :)

Comment: What you could do is to develop a webAPI that use their webAPI and then ask them to host it (Which they would probably refuse).

That webAPI could encrypt the data using autogenerated rsa-256 certificate which would encrypt the data. then you would have to decryt the data on your side.